# "[Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iomm" after kernel update

Tags: boot, kernel, mac, macbook-pro

I'm on a macbook pro and I installed Ubuntu alongside osx. It works really well except the handling of lid closure, so I upgraded the kernel to 4.4.8 in order to see if it can fix the problem.

In order to update the kernel I downloaded the 3 files from [ubuntu server](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/), specifically:

- linux-headers-4.4.8-040408_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_all.deb
- linux-headers-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb
- linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb

Then I ran:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

It seems that now it works properly (the mac stops on the lid closure and resume on the lid opening). But, unfortunately I'm experiencing booting errors, and often I have to pass through recovery mode in order to avoid a black screen after a normal boot.

The following is the output of `dmesg -H -l err`:

```
[mag 5 08:25] DMAR-IR: [Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iommu, interrupt remapping will be disabled
[  +1,128578] pci 0000:00:01.0: ASPM: Could not configure common clock
[  +5,719675] irq 17: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[  +0,000075] handlers:
[  +0,000011] [<ffffffffc009bb60>] sdhci_irq [sdhci] threaded [<ffffffffc0098300>] sdhci_thread_irq [sdhci]
```

What should I do?

ps: I have also a series of warnings that I don't understand and I'm unable to fix:

```
[  +0,039937] DMAR-IR: Failed to enable irq remapping. You are vulnerable to irq-injection attacks.
[  +0,044239]  #2
[  +0,003141]  #3
[  +0,003114]  #4 #5 #6 #7
[  +0,041626] PCCT header not found.
[  +0,017443] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[  +0,000010] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF880265716000 0008AD (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20100915)
[  +0,000461] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[  +0,000007] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF88026571BC00 0003A4 (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20100915)
[  +0,000387] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[  +0,000004] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF880265706E00 000119 (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20100915)
[  +0,001185] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20150930/hwxface-580)
[  +0,000003] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20150930/hwxface-580)
[  +1,065977] ACPI: Enabled 3 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
[  +0,019243] pci 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[  +0,000001] pci 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
[  +0,551329] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[  +0,000002] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
[  +1,437917] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.IGPU._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[  +0,000021] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[  +0,150594] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(GFX0) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[  +3,511571] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.8-040408-generic #201604200335
[  +0,000001] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookPro10,1/Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F, BIOS MBP101.88Z.00EE.B0A.1509111559 09/11/2015
[  +0,000001]  0000000000000086 722e6f5e5debc82e ffff88026f203e60 ffffffff813cee93
[  +0,000002]  ffff8802609e5000 ffff8802609e50b4 ffff88026f203e88 ffffffff810dc0e3
[  +0,000001]  ffff8802609e5000 0000000000000000 0000000000000011 ffff88026f203ec0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `irqpoll` and `intremap=off` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` setting into `/etc/default/grub` file. For example run `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` and change the line in question so that after your edit it might say (depending on what parameters were already there):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash irqpoll intremap=off"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

More details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317252) and [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37008/ioapic-2-has-no-mapping/).

Comment: This doesn't fix it

Answer (score -1):

Total newb, but came here looking for answers and mine got fixed. I didn't see what I did listed, but here's what I did.
When my computer (2012 MacBook) boots, it gives me the option to boot into linux mint advanced options. I do that and it gives me the error listed above. I typed 'fsck' and it told me a file that was damaged and I typed fsck /sda (whatever was listed) and then it gave me the option to go into a fix mode and I ran several fixes and then it allowed me to continue to boot. Wish I had taken better notes, but I figured it wasn't a bios problem because I could still boot into MacOS.